# How to resolve this runtime-error occurring in Simple Calculator Program - B. Stroustrup's PPP's, Ch. 7?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, error-handling, runtime-error

I'm learning C++ using B. Stroustrup's PPP, 1st edition. I was testing this simple calculator after completing Q9. from the Ch.7 exercises by giving random inputs to the calculator.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and this is the complete code of the calculator I'm using -

```
// This program is an simple calculator

/*
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

>>> Grammar used in this program to handle expressions and features <<<

    Calculator:
        Statement
        Quit
        Print
        Help
        Calculator Statement

    Print:
        ";"

    Quit:
        "q"

    Statement:
        Declaration
        Assignment
        Expression

    Declaration:
        "let" Name "=" Expression
        "const" Name "=" Expression

    Assignment:
        "set" Name "=" Expression

    Name:
        string-literal-starting-with-alphabet-or-underscore-and-contains-only-alphabets-underscores-&-numbers

    Expression:
        Term
        Expression "+" Term
        Expression "-" Term

    Term:
        Primary
        Term "*" Primary
        Term "/" Primary
        Term "%" Primary

    Primary:
        Number
        Name
        "(" Expression ")"
        "+" Primary
        "-" Primary
        "pow(" Primary "," Primary ")"
        "sqrt(" Primary ")"

    Number:
        floating-point-literal


    Input comes from cin through Token_stream called ts, in the form of Tokens.
*/

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

struct Token {
    char kind;                      // kind of Token
    double value;                   // for numbers: value of Token
    string name;                    // for variables: name of variables
    Token(char ch) :kind(ch), value(0) { }
    Token(char ch, double val) :kind(ch), value(val) { }
    Token(char ch, string var) :kind(ch), name(var) { }
};

class Token_stream {
public:
    Token_stream() :full(0), buffer(0) { }
    Token get();                                    // get Tokens from Token_stream
    void unget(Token t) { buffer = t; full = true; }    // putback Token into Token_stream
    void ignore(char c);                            // ignore characters till c is found, including c
private:
    bool full;                                      // buffer status
    Token buffer;                                   // buffer to store single Token
};


// Token.kind symbolic constants
const char let = '#';           // for variale-declaration
const char set = '@';           // for assignment
const char constant = '!';      // for constant-declaration
const char quit = 'Q';          // quit application
const char print = ';';         // print expression-output
const char number = '8';        // for number
const char name = 'a';          // for variable-name
const char sqroot = 'R';        // square root
const char power = 'P';         // power/order
//const char variabletype = 'v';    // variable type in Variable
//const char constanttype = 'c';    // constant type in Variable
const char help = 'h';          // help - instructions/examples/features

const string declkey = "let";   // declaration keyword, like let x = 2; to declare a new variable x
const string assignkey = "set"; // assignment keyword, like set x = 3; where x is a declared variable
const string quit1key = "quit"; // quit keyword 1
const string quit2key = "exit"; // quit keyword 2
const string quit3key = "q";    // quit keyword 3
const string powerkey = "pow";  // for using power function
const string sqrtkey = "sqrt";  // for using square root function
const string constkey = "const";// for declaring a symbolic constant, not a variable
const string help1key = "H";    // help keyword 1
const string help2key = "h";    // help keyword 2
const string help3key = "help"; // help keyword 3
const string help4key = "HELP"; // help keyword 4
const string help5key = "Help"; // help keyword 5

Token Token_stream::get()
{
    if (full) { full = false; return buffer; }
    char ch;
    cin.get(ch);
    switch (ch) {
    case '(':
    case ')':
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '*':
    case '/':
    case '%':
    case print:
        //case quit:
        //case let:
    case '=':   // during variable/constant-initialization, assignment
    case ',':   // pow(x , i);
        return Token(ch);
    case '.':
    case '0':
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
    case '9':
    {   cin.unget();
    double val;
    cin >> val;
    return Token(number, val);
    }
    default:
        if (isalpha(ch) || ch == '_') {             // check for alphabet
            string s;
            s += ch;
            while (cin.get(ch) && (isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch) || ch == '_')) s += ch;   // store only alphabets, numbers & underscores
            cin.unget();
            if (s == declkey) return Token(let);    // is current statement a variable-declaration?
            if (s == constkey) return Token(constant);  // is current statement a constant-declaration?
            if (s == assignkey) return Token(set);  // is current statement an assignment?
            if (s == quit1key || s == quit2key || s == quit3key) return Token(quit);    // user wants to quit?
            if (s == help1key || s == help2key || s == help3key || s == help4key || s == help5key) return Token(help); // user needs help?
            if (s == sqrtkey) return Token(sqroot); // square root of expression
            if (s == powerkey) return Token(power); // pow(x,i) = x^i = x*x*...*x (i times)
            return Token(name, s);                  // it's a variable name then
        }
        else if (isspace(ch)){
            if (ch == '\n')
                return Token(print);
            else
                return get();
        }
        error("Bad token");
    }
}

void Token_stream::ignore(char c)       // ignore all characters till & including c
{
    if (full && c == buffer.kind) {
        full = false;
        return;
    }
    full = false;

    char ch;
    while (cin.get(ch))
        if (ch == c) return;
}

struct Variable {
    string name;
    double value;
    char type;
    Variable(string n, double v, char c) :name(n), value(v), type(c) { }
};

class Table {
public:
    double get(string s);
    void set(string s, double d);
    double declare(string s, double val, char type);
    bool is_declared(string s);
private:
    vector<Variable> var_table;
};

Table symbol_table;

double Table::get(string s)         // get value of declared variable with name s
{
    for (int i = 0; i < var_table.size(); ++i)
        if (var_table[i].name == s) return var_table[i].value;
    error("get: undefined name ", s);
}

void Table::set(string s, double d)     // set value of declared variable with name s to d
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= var_table.size(); ++i)
        if (var_table[i].name == s) {
            if (var_table[i].type == constant)
                error("set: can't change the value of a constant");
            var_table[i].value = d;
            return;
        }
    error("set: undefined name ", s);
}

bool Table::is_declared(string s)       // check if a variable with name s is declared
{
    for (int i = 0; i < var_table.size(); ++i)
        if (var_table[i].name == s) return true;
    return false;
}

double Table::declare(string s, double d, char type)
{
    if (is_declared(s))
        error("declare: variable already exists ", s);
    var_table.push_back(Variable(s, d, type));

    return d;
}

Token_stream ts;

double expression();

double primary()                // Primary:
{
    Token t = ts.get();
    switch (t.kind) {
    case '(':                   //      "(" Expression ")"
    {
        double d = expression();
        t = ts.get();
        if (t.kind != ')') error("primary: '(' expected");
        return d;
    }
    case '-':                   //      "-" Primary
        return -primary();
    case '+':                   //      "+" Primary
        return primary();
    case number:                //      floating-point-number
        return t.value;
    case name:                  //      value of variable with name t.name
        return symbol_table.get(t.name);
    case sqroot:                //      sqrt(x) or "sqrt" Primary
    {
        double d = primary();
        if (d < 0) error("negative square root");
        return sqrt(d);
    }
    case power:
    {
        t = ts.get();                               // check for '('
        if (t.kind != '(')
            error("power_primary: '(' expected");

        double d1 = expression();

        t = ts.get();
        if (t.kind != ',')
            error("power_primary: ',' expected");

        double d2 = expression();

        t = ts.get();
        if (t.kind != ')')
            error("power_primary: ')' expected");

        int i = narrow_cast<int>(d2);
        //if (d2 - int(d2) > 0)
        //  error("power_primary: 2nd argument invalid, must be an integer");
        //if (d1 == 0 && d2 == 0)
        //  error("power_primary: pow(0,0) is undefined");
        return pow(d1, i);
    }
    default:
        error("primary expected");
    }
}

double term()                   // Term:
{
    double left = primary();    //      Primary
    while (true) {
        Token t = ts.get();
        switch (t.kind) {
        case '*':               //      Term "*" Primary
            left *= primary();
            break;
        case '/':               //      Term "/" Primary
        {
            double d = primary();
            if (d == 0) error("divide by zero");
            left /= d;
            break;
        }
        case '%':               //      Term "%" Primary
        {
            double d = primary();
            int i1 = narrow_cast<int>(left);
            int i2 = narrow_cast<int>(d);
            if (i2 == 0)
                error("term: modulo by zero");
            left = i1%i2;
            break;
        }
        default:                // return term-value
            ts.unget(t);
            return left;
        }
    }
}

double expression()             // Expression:
{
    double left = term();       //      Term
    while (true) {
        Token t = ts.get();
        switch (t.kind) {
        case '+':               //      Expression "+" Term
            left += term();
            break;
        case '-':               //      Expression "-" Term
            left -= term();
            break;
        default:                // return expression-value
            ts.unget(t);
            return left;
        }
    }
}

double declaration()            // assuming "let" has been found
{
    Token t = ts.get();
    char type;
    type = t.kind;

    t = ts.get();
    if (t.kind != name) error("declaration: name expected in declaration");     // check if the Token read is a name

    string name = t.name;

    Token t2 = ts.get();
    if (t2.kind != '=') error("declaration: '=' missing in declaration of ", name);     // expecting a '=' after variable name

    double d = expression();            // everything right so far, get the initial value of the variable

    return symbol_table.declare(name, d, type); // store new variable/constant in vector names
}

double assignment()             // assuming "set" has been found
{
    Token t = ts.get();
    if (t.kind != name)         // check if the Token read is a name
        error("assignment: name expected in declaration");

    string var = t.name;
    if (!symbol_table.is_declared(var))     // check if the variable is declared or not
        error("assignment: can't assign value to an undeclared variable");

    t = ts.get();               // check for '='
    if (t.kind != '=')
        error("assignment: '=' expected in declaration of ", var);

    double newval = expression();   // get new value of variable var
    symbol_table.set(var, newval);          // set new value
    return newval;
}

double statement()
{
    Token t = ts.get();
    switch (t.kind) {
    case let:                   // is it a variable-declaration?
    case constant:              // is it a constant-declaration?
        ts.unget(t);
        return declaration();
    case set:                   // or an assignment?
        return assignment();
    default:                    // or an expression?
        ts.unget(t);
        return expression();
    }
}

void clean_up_mess()
{
    ts.ignore(print);       // ignore characters till and including 'print' character
}

const string prompt_str = "> ";
const string result_str = "= ";

void calculate()
{
    // Welcome message
    cout << "  This program is a basic calculator\n"
        << "  To know more use - 'help'\n"
        << "  To quit use - 'quit' or 'exit'\n\n";
    while (true)
        try {
        cout << prompt_str;
        Token t = ts.get();                     // get a token
        while (t.kind == print) t = ts.get();   // eat all 'print' tokens
        if (t.kind == quit) return;             // 'quit' token?
        else if (t.kind == help){
            // Instructions to use calculator
            cout << "\n  INSTRUCTIONS TO USE -\n"
                << "\t1. Operations supported: +, -, *, /, % (last one for integers only), sqrt(x), pow(x,y) (y is an integer).\n"
                << "\t2. Use expressions like 1+2/3*4-5, followed by " << print << " to terminate expression.\n"
                << "\t3. Use square brackets or parenthesis or both in expressions as usual, for example, (1-2)*{(3-4)/2}.\n";
            // Features
            cout << "\n  FEATURES -\n"
                << "\t1. Evaluate multiple expressions at once. Enter more than one expressions in a line and see them get evaluated at once.\n"
                << "\t2. Use variables for easy calculation. Declare them like this, \"let x = 6;\" or write any expression in place of '6'.\n"
                << "\t3. Assign new values to already declared variables like this, \"set x = 3;\"\n"
                << "\t4. Use constants like 'pi' & 'e' in statements instead of remembering their values.\n"
                << "\t5. Declare your own constants like this, \"const pi = 3.1415\"\n"
                << "\t6. Ask for help anytime, use \"Help\" or \"help\" or \"HELP\" or \"h\" or \"H\"\n"
                << "\t7. Want to quit, just type \"quit\" or \"exit\"\n"
                << "\n";
            //continue;
        }
        else{
            ts.unget(t);                            // some other token was read, so unread it, put it back in Token_stream
            cout << result_str << statement() << endl;  // read 'statement' from the input stream, and evaluate it, and print its result
        }
    }
    catch (runtime_error& e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        clean_up_mess();
    }
    catch (...){
        cerr << "Oops, unknown exception" << endl;
        clean_up_mess();
    }
}

int main()
{
    try {
        // pre-defined symbolic constants
        symbol_table.declare("k", 1000, constant);  // k = 1000 like pi = 3.1415926535(not defined here)

        calculate();

        char c;
        while (cin.get(c) && c != print && c != '\n');
        cout << "\n\n  You've now exited the program.\n"
            << "  Enter x to close this window.\n\n  ";
        while (cin >> c && c == 'x')
            break;

        return 0;
    }
    catch (exception& e) {
        cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << endl;
        char c;
        while (cin >> c && c != print);
        return 1;
    }
    catch (...) {
        cerr << "Oops: Unknown exception\n";
        char c;
        while (cin >> c && c != print);
        return 2;
    }
}
```

But I've found that the program gives this error

[image]

whenever I provide it input of the form "*some_real_number_here* **e** *string_starting_with_alphabet*", without any whitespace, with last string being optional and it happens with **e** only and not with any other alphabet (hopefully because I haven't tried each & every combination of numbers & alphabets).

What is this error? How to resolve this?

Here is the library [`std_lib_facilities.h`](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h) .

**If you're testing the program too, then** at the end of every input/expression to the program, have `;` for letting the program `clean_up_mess()` easily.

Hopefully, this is the **file mentioned in the error window**, [`isctype.c`](http://ideone.com/64KggA).

---

For example -

**Input:** `2e;` or `4easdf123;`     **Output:** *The above mentioned error*

Other weird outputs -

**Input:** `2e12;`    **Output:** `2e+12`

**Input:** `3e1;`     **Output:** `30`

---

**Edit:** It might be the case (discussed in comments) that `Token_stream::get()` function when trying to read a floating-point number like 2e+11, gives error because of expecting a number whenever `>>` sees something like this - "*number* **e** *anything*" (without whitespace) and when it finds an alphabet in *anything* instead of an integer, it throws an exception.

Comment: Please tell us which is the line with the failing assert (line 56).

Comment: If you input *"some_real_number_here `e` anything_here"*, the program will try to parse that with `double val; cin >> val;` - there needs to be a valid exponent after the `e` for that to succeed. It bothers me that the success of the parsing ostensibly isn't tested before the Token's created and returned, but I have dug around to see if exceptions were enabled.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini I don't know where such a file exists, there exists no `F:` drive on my pc. I'm trying my best.

Comment: @TonyD So what can I do to fix this? Should I read numbers in `default:` too after the case for string?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: the failing assertion is in the C runtime, and not in the given code (which contains no assertions).

Comment: @PalashV: you could try `double val; if (!(cin >> val)) error("invalid numeric value");` and see where it gets caught - I haven't looked, but that'd be the first step.

Comment: @TonyD: The `calculate()` function catches it. Now what should I do?

Comment: The problem is that the user has given bad or unexpected input.  The program was expecting a number, and didn't get one.  What can the program do?  This is error handling, which I'm sure will be covered in later chapters, but there's something of a philosophical question here:  what makes sense?  Personally, I think the thing that makes the most sense is to tell the user that the request couldn't be satisfied, and then to go onto the next request.

Comment: @MaxLybbert: Hmm... Thanks. So I should tell the user about the error and ask for another valid input, right?

Comment: That's a great way to handle the error, yes.